# jQuery .show() and .toggleClass("foo") on one object at the same time?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-isotope

Sandbox code below (using the [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) layout and sorting plugin). What shall happen:

1. If an .item is clicked, it shall grow to reveal more of its content (.maximise)
2. If *that same* .item is clicked again, it shall shrink to hide most of its content (.minimise)
3. If *any other* .item is clicked, it shall do 1. *and all others* shall do 2.

   ```
   $items = $('.item'); // solution

   $('.item').click(function () {

   var $this = $(this);
   var $previousSelected = $('.selected');

   if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

       $items.not(this).find('.slideshow').removeClass('transparent'); // solution

       $(this).removeClass('selected');
       $(this).children('.maximise').hide();
       $(this).children('.minimise').show();

   } else {

       $items.not(this).find('.slideshow').addClass('transparent'); // solution

       $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
       $previousSelected.children('.minimise').show();
       $previousSelected.children('.maximise').hide();

       $(this).addClass('selected');
       $(this).children('.minimise').hide();
       $(this).children('.maximise').show();
   }

   // $container.isotope('shuffle'); uncomment to always randomise layout
   // $container.isotope('reLayout'); uncomment if no sorting logic is used
   $container
   .isotope('updateSortData', $this)
   .isotope('updateSortData', $previousSelected)
   .isotope();
   });
   ```

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT** Found .find(). and then .not() methods and then realised to just store all Isotope elements in $items = $('.item');

Comment: I toggle classes like that quite often and it is a good approach.

Comment: a quick tip: you can remove the previousSelected. Instead you can do this: $(this).addClass('selected').siblins().removeClass('selected')

Comment: Cheers, didn't know that these family relations work like this - siblings

Comment: So, it looks like for this "select and modify one div - deselect and modify all others" type of functionality, I must .find() .each() .item, that is NOT the one just clicked on. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery's `addClass` method. jQuery will check to see if the .transparent class is already set on the element before it adds it in.

```
$($previousSelected).children('.minimise').addClass('transparent').show();
```

You may also want to remove the transparent class when you hide it, in which case I would remove the class after `.hide()`:

```
$($previousSelected).children('.maximise').hide().removeClass('transparent');
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems right. However, I can't see the class .transparent being added in Google's devtool display. Strange.

Comment: I had trouble seeing changes before too.. are you looking in the "Elements" tab?

Comment: I amended the code in my question, so now it finds the right child of .minimise. In the devtool, I usually right-click on the element I want to observe and, yes, I can see the .transparent class added in the right place (.slideshow which is a child of .minimise). All that's left now is in my comment under the original question...

Answer (score 2):

Tip: If you have a selector query already stored in a object(variable), you don't need to use it again within a selector, you can just use the object.

```
var $previousSelected = $('.selected');

...
//$($previousSelected).removeClass('selected');
$previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
```